# How to ignore larger files from pushing to github?

Tags: git, github

I am new to git and tried to push my project directory to github.

Below are the step I followed.

```
git init

git add .

git commit -m 'first commit'

git push <my repo address>
```

Then below error throws.

```
Counting objects: 95, done.
Delta compression using up to 32 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (73/73), done.
Writing objects: 100% (77/77), 920.61 MiB | 27.90 MiB/s, done.
Total 77 (delta 37), reused 1 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (37/37), completed with 10 local objects.
remote: warning: File images/log is 60.77 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recom                                                      mended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File S                                                      torage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: c3704dac955cd6d24c55bfab021fbe2a
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File images/sql-push-image1.iso is 349.21 MB; this                                                       exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File images/sql-push-image1.SPA.bin is 570.62 MB; this excee                                                      ds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File images/sql-push-image2.SPA.bin is 348.69 MB; t                                                      his exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File images/sql-push-image1.ova is 349.49 MB; this                                                       exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To https://github.com/mohandev/sql-qa.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/mohandev/sql-qa.git
```

many refernced to create .gitignore file to ignore files. so created the .gitignore file with below content

```
*.iso
*.bin
*.ova
```

Then executed below commands

```
git add .

git commit -m 'ignoring certian image files'

git push
```

But again the same error has thrown.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: You may check the answer on this specific problem on StackOverflow
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61457780/8748450

Answer (score 0):

if you write gitignore that just contain :

```
*.iso
*.bin
*.ova
```

the git just ignore file *.iso *.bin and *.ova on your root directory, but not on your images/ directory,

you can try :

```
images/*.iso
images/*.bin
images/.ova
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible fix:

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch images/*.bin images/*.ova images/*.iso'
```

as described [here](https://marcosantonocito.medium.com/fixing-the-gh001-large-files-detected-you-may-want-to-try-git-large-file-storage-43336b983272)